# What happens when you log a constant greater or smaller than 1?

Tags: calculus

Right now I am working through some questions (general solution differential equations)

What I have learnt is that if I have a question such as

lny= $2x^2$ +4x +c , it would be equal to

y=ke^($2x^2$ + 4x), letting k=$e^c$

But what if the constant is greater than 1

lny= $2x^2$ +4x +4c

Would the constant 4c also be equal to k or would it be equal to 4k? In the same case, what if the constant is smaller than one

lny= $2x^2$ +4x +0.5c

Would the equal 0.5 c be equal to k or would it be equal to 0.5k?

This is what im not sure about

Comment: If $x \ge e$ then $\ln x \ge 1$.  If $1\le x < e$ then $0 \le \ln x < 1$  And if $0< x < 1$ then $\ln x< 0$.  That's all.

Comment: In the first case, it isn't $k=c$, but $k=e^c$.  Also, in order to get the MathJax commands to work, you have to surround them with `$` signs.  `$e^c$` typesets as $e^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it

$\ln y = 2x^2 + 4x + c$ so

$e^{\ln y} = e^{2x^2 + 4x + c}$

$y = e^c*e^{2x^2 + 4x} = ke^{2x^2 + 4x}$ where $k = e^c$.

So letting $k = c$ was just plain wrong.

$\ln y = 4x^2 + 4x + 4c$ means

$y = e^{4c}y^{4x^2 + 4x}=my^{4x^2 + 4x} = k^4y^{4x^2 + 4x}$ where $m = e^{4c}$ and $k = e^c$

ANd $\ln y = 4x^2 + 4x + 0.5c$ means

$y = e^{0.5c}e^{4x^2+4x}=m e^{4x^2+4x}=\sqrt k e^{4x^2 + 4x}$ where $m = e^{0.5c}$ and $k = e^c$.

Answer (score 1):

if $e^c=k$ (I supouse there's a typo in the question in the part 'k=c') then $e^{4c}=k^4$ since $e^{4c}=(e^c)^4$, similar to any exponent $e^{ct}=k^{t}$

but the $k$ is just the way to say "there's some real number there" it doesnt matter if you take $c$ or $2c$ or $0.5c$ , k is going to be the same always when you solve the $IVP$